# mysql result is json array and i want to put array key in php variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

i have mysql result in json multidimensional array like this:

```
{'BrandTransactionItems': [
        {'ServiceCode':'PATROL_FIX','AbonentCode': 'ელ562705','Amount': 10.0
        },
        {'ServiceCode':'PATROL_FIX','AbonentCode': 'ელ606219','Amount': 10.0
        },
    ], 'BrandCode': 'jarima',   'Language': 'ge', 'ReturnUrl': 'http: //jarima.ge/'}
```

i want to get from this array only Amount value in php variable.  how? can you help me?

Comment: If that really is your string, it is not valid json.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `json_decode`:

```
$json = "{'BrandTransactionItems':[{'ServiceCode':'PATROL_FIX','AbonentCode': 'ელ562705','Amount': 10.0 },{'ServiceCode':'PATROL_FIX','AbonentCode': 'ელ606219','Amount': 10.0 },], 'BrandCode': 'jarima',   'Language': 'ge', 'ReturnUrl': 'http://jarima.ge/'}";
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach ($array['BrandTransactionItems'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "Amount") {
    $result[] = $value;
  }
return $result;
```

The `$result` variable now holds every 'Amount' value from the original JSON.

Comment: You cannot use `json_decode()` as the string is not valid json (it needs double instead of single quotes).

Comment: @jeroen and a comma with no following object.

Comment: @FirstOne I didn't even get that far :-)

Comment: this code return this Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in.... 79 line is: foreach ($array['BrandTransactionItems'] as $key => $value) {

Comment: For This code: <?php
 

$json = '{"BrandTransactionItems":{"ServiceCode":"CTPPEN_FIX","AbonentCode":"421481104","Amount":"10.0"},"BrandCode":"jarima","Language":"ge","ReturnUrl":"http:\/\/jarima.ge\/"}';
$array = json_decode($json);
foreach ($array["BrandTransactionItems"] as $key => $value) {
  if ($key == "Amount")
  {
    $result[] = $value;
  }
return $result;
}
  
 
  ?> is same error:


Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

PS For This Example JSON is Valid